# Dagger android studio 3

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyFhqydqLzM&t=484s in the minute 7:31, but in my project, I have a problem and don't detect the Dagger component,

I attached the picture

[image]

the dependencies that I am using

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`
```

Comment: Try to `Build` project

Comment: Thanks bro!!! I never thought that the answer was so easy...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Dagger code is generated, simply try to `Build` project.

Answer (score 0):

Dagger create classes at compile time, so this is just temporary error. You need to run your application, it will get remove automatically.